# PowerShell\WPF: Emtpy Radio Button Object in PowerShell using datatemplate

Tags: wpf, powershell, datatemplate

**I am currently using a data template for radio buttons and textblocks to be autogenerated by values pulled from an excel spreadsheet. It works however, I'm having an issue where the RadioButton object appears in my variable $form(wpf items) array but the value of it is null.**

Here is my WPF. if you would like to see the PowerShell Code i can attach as well.

```
<Page x:Name="templateMenu" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
  mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="templateMenu" 
    Height="450" Width="400"
    Background="Transparent">

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBlock.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ToggleButton.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="C:\Users\Tre\Documents\repo\boip creation tool\Utils\CustomToolBar.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Border Background="#212C3E"
        CornerRadius="20">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="91*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="248*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolBarTray VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="76" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent">
            <ToolBar x:Name="templateMenuToolBar">

                <Button x:Name="templateMenuBtnClose" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}"
                        Content= "{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Close}"
                        Foreground="White"
                        materialDesign:RippleAssist.Feedback="#DD000000"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ControlsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" IsCancel="True"/>

            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

        <TextBlock x:Name="templateMenuTitleOne" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Select Template to Create BOIPS" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   FontSize="24"
                   Foreground="#FFFFD960" 
                   Width="260"
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                   Height="64"  
                   Grid.Row="1" Margin="70,14,70,13"/>

       <StackPanel x:Name="tempMenuPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="auto">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White" CornerRadius="10" Height="auto" Margin="8,5,8,5">
            
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="templateOptions"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding templateOptions}"
                          Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                          Height="238" Width="383">
                     

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioBtnTemplate">
                                <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Padding="8">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition
                                             SharedSizeGroup="Checkerz" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         <RadioButton 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Foreground="#FF2095F2" 
                                            GroupName="Main">
                                            <RadioButton.Resources>
                                                <!--Unchecked state-->
                                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff" Color="#FF2095F2"/>
                                                <!--Checked state-->
                                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#FF2095F2"/>
                                            </RadioButton.Resources>
                                        </RadioButton>
                                        <StackPanel
                                        Margin="8 0 0 0"
                                        Grid.Column="1">
                                            <TextBlock
                                            Text="{Binding Template Type}"
                                            FontWeight="Bold"
                                            Foreground="#2095F2" />
                                            <TextBlock
                                            Text="{Binding Description}"
                                            Foreground="black"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                
                            </Border>
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                  Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                  Value="True">
                                    <Setter
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSelection}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="5" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Template>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="BtnBacktemplateMenu" Content="Back" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Grid.Row="3" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="#2095F2"
                    Height="32" Width="130"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignRaisedLightButton}" Background="#FF18202D" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="35,13,35,16"/>

        <Button x:Name="BtnNexttemplateMenu" Content="Next" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="#FFFFD960"
                    Height="32" Width="130"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignRaisedLightButton}" Background="#FF18202D" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="35,13,35,16" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**Here is a snippet of the GUI. Like mentioned above the display works however, the object in PowerShell is null and does not show up as an radio buttton which is my issue.**
[image]

Repo:https://github.com/creationsoftre/wpf-datatemp-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing itemsControl  to a listbox utilizing selectedValue, SelectedIndex to control my autogenerated radio buttons.

PowerShell Code

```
$wpf.menuListBox.add_SelectionChanged({
    $wpf.BtnNexttemplateMenu.IsEnabled = $true
    
    if($wpf.menuListBox.SelectedIndex -lt $wpf.menuListBox.Items.Count){
        $selectedItem = $wpf.menuListBox.SelectedValue.'Template Type'
    }
})
```

Xaml Code

```
<ListBox x:Name="menuListBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding dataContent}"
        Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
        Height="238" Width="383">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border x:Name="Border"
            Padding="8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition
                         SharedSizeGroup="Checkerz" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Foreground="#FF2095F2" 
                        GroupName="Templates"
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}">
                        <RadioButton.Resources>
                            <!--Unchecked state-->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff" Color="#FF2095F2"/>
                            <!--Checked state-->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#FF2095F2"/>
                        </RadioButton.Resources>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <StackPanel
                    Margin="8 0 0 0"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Template Type}"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Foreground="#2095F2" />
                        <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Description}"
                        Foreground="black"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid> 
            </Border>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                  Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                  Value="True">
                    <Setter
                    TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSelection}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter Margin="5" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```